# What do these article submission dates really mean?

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I want to submit a paper to a conference in the field of Computer Science, but I am a little bit doubtful of what information to submit. The dates are the following:

- Abstract Submission Deadline: February 6, 2015
- All Acceptance Communications: March 16, 2015
- Preliminary Paper Submission Deadline: April 27, 2015
- Peer Review Final Acceptance Communication: June 1, 2015
- Final Camera-Ready Paper Submission & Copyright Deadline and Author Registration Deadline: July 10, 2015
- Early Registration & Hotel Deadline: September 22, 2015

I am in the process of finishing the paper, but I think that I will not make it for the first deadline to complete it throughly. For what I know the Abstract Submission Deadline is only for submitting the abstract, am I right? I believe that is for the chair to have an overview of how many papers will they have.

The question that I have is: what does All Acceptance Communications means? Is it the submission of the full paper? Why just don't they call it Full paper submission instead of that other cryptic name?

Answer (score 6):

This set of deadlines sounds like the conferences is doing two rounds of review for submissions.

- First, you send in an abstract in February, and they decide if it's worth reviewing a full paper by mid-March.
- If they invite a full paper, you send it in by late April, and they send a final accept/reject by the beginning of June.
- Final versions of accepted papers have to be submitted by mid-July.

Their names could be a bit better, but it seems fairly clear to me that this is their intention.  If you're concerned it may be otherwise, it's always OK to write to the conference contact email to check your understanding.